# Hadoop HDFS connection in PowerCenter

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, informatica-powercenter

I have installed Cloudera's Hadoop QuickStart VM and I am attempting to pass records from my local database to HDFS using a PowerCenter mapping.
I've set up the Hadoop_HDFS_Connection in PowerCenter Workflow Manager but when I run the workflow I get the following error: "Unable to establish a connection with the specified HDFS host".  It gives a "java.net.ConnectionException" error when trying to connect to the host name and port.
I think the error may be in the hostname notation. On Cloudera Manager on the VM, the host name is listed as 'localhost.localdomain' but I don't know how to translate this in the PowerCenter connection settings.

Anybody got this connection to work?

Many thanks.

Brian

Comment: you might need to ensure that the hostname is appropriately specified.. also check whether you are able to reach that host using non informatica connection channels !!!